# Can I generate a C/C++ client for a JAX-RS JSON API?

Tags: java, c++, c, json, jax-rs

Suppose I have a remote JAX-RS JSON API from a server running Tomcat. I want to access this API from a C/C++ client. Are there any tools available to make life easier for the C/C++ client, e.g. code generators? Or does anybody have a suggestion for an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of such a tool.  More to the point, I suspect that such a tool (a C / C++ generator for JSON) is impractical.

There are a number of reasons why.  Some of the most significant ones are:

- A key problem is that JSON doesn't have schemas.  This means that an API generator would have to resort to looking at example messages and try to infer what fields to expect and what their types are.  This can be difficult and even theoretically impossible in some cases.
- In languages like Java and C#, there are straight-forward "right ways" to generate object APIs; e.g. the JavaBeans conventions.  In C++ and especially C, the conventions are not there, and there are complicating issues like container protocols and memory management to deal with.
- In languages like Java and C# are runtime type-safe, and have various language level mechanisms are provided that allow you to use dynamic programming to deal with the JSON's schema-less nature.  For example, in Java you have reflection, proxy classes, dynamic code generation and dynamic code loading, all of which can help in dealing with JSON.  In C and C++, these mechanisms are generally unavailable.

In short, if you are using C or C++, JSON libraries are as good as it will get.

**FOLLOWUP**

As a comment points out, this may be feasible to implement in the context of a *specific* JAX-RS-based server implementation.  You'd need to get hold of the internal metadata, apply the JSON mapping to it, and generate C / C++ APIs from that.  The problems are:

1. The generator implementation would be platform specific.
2. The C / C++ based client would not be able to cope with changes to the effective schema without regeneration of the APIs and corresponding client code changes.  (By contrast, a JSON library-based solution can in theory be coded to deal with unexpected new attributes, etc)
3. You still have the container / memory management problem to deal with.

Comment: I am sure you are correct if you only consider JSON. However, I believe with JAX-RS there would be a Java-based schema from which to generate value objects in another language. I think the question is more if someone has done it yet. JBoss RestEasy claims they have provided something in Java.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is your choice of library for sending and receiving http requests, and a json parser. Nothing is going to generate code to make it easier for you because the idea of such an API is that it spits out JSON. The point of JSON is to go across language and transport barriers in a consistent way. A bit like XML, but simpler.

This question might interest you: [what's the best json parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser)? [JSON Spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/JSON_Spirit.aspx) Looks like a particularly good article.

Now, as you're using REST, all you need is to communicate to the right urls. Done.

The final thing you want to decide is what libary to use for network communication. Boost would be many people's recommendation, I'm sure.

Comment: I know what JSON is for and that there are libraries for it, but I don't want to write all the boilerplate code that parses it into C/C++ structs/classes. And I also don't want to change everything again when there is a new class or or field. That's why I am looking for an automated solution.